# What is the "(1)" in git(1) for?

Tags: git

While searching for informations about Git commands in the documentation, I noticed some commands has been named with `(1)` (`git(1)`, `git-checkout(1)`, `git-reset(1)`) and some with `(7)` (`gittutorial(7)`)

Does it correspond to the number of possible parameter ?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's the type of `man` page. `man`'s manuals are split into several sections, chapter 1 is for executables, and `git` is an executable. The whole list is given by `man man`:

```
1   Executable programs or shell commands
2   System calls (functions provided by the kernel)
3   Library calls (functions within program libraries)
4   Special files (usually found in /dev)
5   File formats and conventions eg /etc/passwd
6   Games
7   Miscellaneous (including macro packages and conventions), e.g. man(7), groff(7)
8   System administration commands (usually only for root)
9   Kernel routines [Non standard]
```

Some things are in multiple sections, like `time` is both a command and a system call, see the difference between `man 1 time` and `man 2 time`.

Answer (score 0):

The numbers means manual (man) section. Each manual is assigned to some section. For example section 1 is for common programs, section 3 for C language functions.

Answer (score 0):

Not really. The number is just an indication of what man page section the command is documented in.

You can find more information here: http://www.unix.com/man-page/Linux/1/man/

Answer (score 0):

There are several "sections" in the **man**ual. A keyword like 'git' or 'read' can refer to many things. For example, `read` can be a bash script function, an executable, a C function, etc. So, you'd find in the man some entries like read(A), read(B), read(C), where the A/B/C numbers would relate to sections about bash, utils and C library.